# How to export and encode a "bytea" column as a Decimal representation in Postgres using PSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, decimal, postgresql-9.1, bytea

I want to export a `bytea` column as a Decimal representation.

The binary exports works as follows:

```
\copy (SELECT right(wantedColumn::text, -1)::varbit FROM "myBigTable" LIMIT 1) TO '/tmp/exported-binary.txt'
```

How can we export `wantedColumn` in `myBigTable` as a Decimal representation ?

Comment: If it is not too large, you can cast `bit` to `bigint`. But why don't you store the data as `numeric` in the first place?

Comment: Re your [recent deleted question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70322838/node-js-vm-module-doesnt-run-asynchronously), here's one approach to fixing it: https://pastebin.com/geVAAzaH Happy coding!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Goddamn you're the man!